# how to get certain column from SQL database?

Tags: android, database

I would like to get a certain column from my sql database using the rows unique column id.
For example my activity is...

```
public class bookLookup extends Activity {
  WebView webView; 
  private DbAdapter mDbHelper; 
  Override public void
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.book_browser);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    myIntent.getExtras.getLong("id");
```

How could i take this id unique id from another activity and get a certain column from the unique id for the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass one query with your DB like "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE YOURCONDITION"