# How to query SQLDatabse for certain Row and Colum?

Tags: android

I would like to query the database by using the certain row id, and then get a certain column. Here is the code im trying to implement it in. Ive tried cursor already but that didnt work.

```
public class bookLookup extends Activity {
WebView webView;
private DbAdapter mDbHelper;
private String bookName;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_browser);  
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    long id = extras.getLong("rowId");


    String url = "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki"+bookName;

    webView.setWebViewClient(new BookLookupbrowser());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about relevant code? Something having to do with your attempt to access the DB. Your other question is just as hopeless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570811/how-to-get-certain-column-from-sql-database

Comment: how the hell do you access the database here? its accessed just by  declaring the variable?

Comment: and 2 questions for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Im sick of seeing these darn [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570811/how-to-get-certain-column-from-sql-database) from you which show no trying... read this and try please!

http://code.google.com/p/android-notes/source/browse/trunk/src/com/bitsetters/android/notes/DBHelper.java?r=10

http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=data